# Django project - two app's two views in one url how to solve

Tags: python, django, django-apps

In my django project i have created one app for log-in users.
And another app for sign-up user. 
But in my .html template both sign-up and log-in function are given on the same page means in one url with one .html file .
Show basically what it means i have to use two apps two different views in one url as well as one .html file . How is it possible
Cannot combine them in one app cause both of the app has lots of other related functionalities also. 
Should i make different app according to the html page/ or one url one app method ?

Comment: 2 separate apps can share the same html template. but what gets displayed can be decided based on the context that you pass to the html to render

Comment: I don't think you need different apps for signup and login users. These two belongs to one functionality category.

Comment: @JohnJosephFernandes But how to add two function(views) in one function ?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki yeah i am also planning to do so if don't get any solution. But i have many other functionalities with sign-up and log-in itself so i had to separate them into two app.

Comment: Would you like to state what other functionalities are there in both apps? It would be easier to figure out that whether you should separate the apps or not

Comment: @sheikhsalman08 you could values from the request object to decide what u want to do and populate you context object . which can get a lil messy but if thats what you want to do it its still possible .

Comment: @ArpitSolanki like deleting user account, updating account i kept with sign-up.  And log-in/log-out .  And if i had to combine them my views.py will have 5/6 views what i am trying to avoid

Comment: @JohnJosephFernandes in my log-in views i just one to send a LogInForm as context , Same for my sign-up view. i want to send another form as RegistrationForm as context.  Now how to combine both the context in one context and render them them with another view

Comment: In standard cases different apps are different logical parts of your project. Your signups and login are parts of authentication app. So I think you should have only one app for this. Also having 5/6views is very normal, you can have many many more views in a single app so don't worry about number of views in a single app

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Very true!!  i think that's the perfect solution for me right now.  But still do you think we should make apps base on the .html file. Means for one template one apps ?

Comment: You can still share templates across the apps. But in general it does not happen much.

Comment: also i think for me i don't need sharing template if i keep them in one app. It's better for me. Really appreciate this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have two views for one URL.

But you can make a view and link the URL to it and in that view decide which function should be used.

If you have both login and signup form in one page then you can use 2 different forms and then decide which function should be used.

This is my solution for you:

1 -  make a single view for your URL

2 - make 2 forms, one for signup and one for login.

3 - in your template add name to your submit buttons and give them a value based on their form:

```
# login form
<form>
    # form fields
    <button type="submit" name="button-name" value="login">
</form>

# signup form
<form>
    # form fields
    <button type="submit" name="button-name" value="signup">
</form>
```

now in your view you can decide which function should be used:

```
if request.POST.get('button-name') and request.POST.get('button-name') == "signup":
    # signup the user
elif request.POST.get('button-name') and request.POST.get('button-name') == "login":
    # login the user
```

i don't recommend you to call another view in this view because views should render a template or ... but i recommend you to make 2 different functions for login and signup which they can be anywhere and call them and decide what you want to do based on what they will return.

Or you can just do everything here.

Comment: Well in my log-in views i just want to render  LogInForm as context , Same for my sign-up view. i want to render another form called RegistrationForm as context. Now how to combine both the context in one context and render that 2 forms context with another view.

Comment: @sheikhsalman08 you can send both forms to template and render them. also you don't have to use django to render your form. you can make a html form yourself and all you need to do is to pick the correct name for your fields. django form uses field names so if you use the same names in your form as your form fields name you're good to go. you can even make a single form with a email and password field and 2 submit button and use this form for both login and signup or just make 2 different forms and send the request to the right Form in your view based on which button used

Comment: But i have used 2 different app. So can't possible in one single view.  I am wondering if there has any solution that the view i have created for registration can i extend that in log-in app view and pass the registration form with log-in form in log-in app.

Comment: @sheikhsalman08 2 different apps doesn't mean you can't use their functions or forms in other apps. you can access their functions in other apps. apps just help you manage your project. you can have one of your forms in login app and another on in signup app, all you need to do is import them where ever you need them and work with theme. you can separate your login and signup functions into their apps and in this view, use them both just like the forms. in this way you have 2 different app with different functions and you can use them anytime in any view or app just like this one. Good Luck ;)

Comment: In one app i have my registration form 
'context = {
  "form1":RegistrationForm,
 }'                                                                                                                          i want add it with another app(log-in) views . Where already it has                                    'context = {
  "form2":LoginForm
 }'. I want also form1 to be inserted into the same context where form2 is inserted. so that i can use it in the same template that i am using for log-in as well as for having one single url.

Comment: i don't understand why you need 2 views? if need 2 form just import the forms into one view and send them to the template like this: `context = { "form1":RegistrationForm,  "form2":LoginForm }`. now you have 2 forms in template. you don't even need the login view and register view. you need 1 view and you can do everything there or call other functions. you can just create a function in your login app which checks for the information and if they are correct it will return a True value and you can login the user on your single view. your main view can be anywhere, in login app or register app

Comment: Yeah that's a nice idea i think. Let me try. Thanks